# ssh, udp and split tunneling accross windows 10

Tags: ssh, proxy, split-tunnel, softether, bitvise

I use "Bitvise SSH client" on my windows 10 machine to Connect to SSH server in windows Server. It doesnt tunnel all of my Pc so use Softether VPN Client Manager To Connect it via Socks Proxy. it Works Nice. now I want to make split tunneling , I mean some request (for example website with .com domain) Connect Direct to Internet and others Go through Proxy. If I dont use softether and set proxy setting in windows 10,I can apply this rule to my Requests. so All .com websites connect Direct to internet, But in this way, Whole Internet doesnt use proxy. How can I Achieve behavior that all PC use proxy except some Request (I mean I want to give Power of softether and power of split tunneling of proxy of windows). If are Any Other method to give the better result, thanks in advance to say me

EDIT:
My Final Goal is connecting to SSH server, all Request in my computer use this except some of them (for example requests to .com)